# How to insert a listing in admin form in magento 2 UI Component method?

Tags: uicomponent, custom, adminform, magento2.4.5p1

I have a Category, and Questions form in my custom module. Questions are added against category.

Each question can be belong to a category or multiple category.
I need to insert a listing on category form edit with the questions belongs to relevant category. I Used `<insertListing>` method in my **ayakil_faq_faq_category_form.xml**

```
<fieldset name="faq_information" sortOrder="10">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Faq Information</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <insertListing name="faq_listing">
        <settings>
            <selectionsProvider>ayakil_faq_faq_listing.ayakil_faq_faq_listing_data_source</selectionsProvider>
            <dataScope>faq_listing</dataScope>
            <ns>faq_listing</ns>
        </settings>
    </insertListing>
</fieldset>
```

I need to perform 2 tasks here,

1- need to pass the category id to the data source and

2 - display the faqs related to the category from faq_table.

With my above steps i am unable to get the grid on form, Can anyone please help on this task.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Refer below link and follow the steps:-**
https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-create-ui-component-grid-and-form/

Comment: thanks for the referance

Answer (score 0):

> **You should follow this file path : vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml**

```
    <insertListing name="customer_address_listing" component="Magento_Customer/js/form/components/insert-listing">
        <settings>
            <dataLinks>
                <exports>false</exports>
                <imports>true</imports>
            </dataLinks>
            <externalProvider>customer_address_listing.customer_address_listing_data_source</externalProvider>
            <selectionsProvider>customer_address_listing.customer_address_listing.customer_address_columns.ids</selectionsProvider>
            <autoRender>true</autoRender>
            <dataScope>customer_address_listing</dataScope>
            <ns>customer_address_listing</ns>
            <exports>
                <link name="parent_id">${ $.externalProvider }:params.parent_id</link>
            </exports>
            <imports>
                <link name="parent_id">${ $.provider }:data.customer.entity_id</link>
                <link name="onAction">ns = ${ $.ns }, index = actions:action</link>
                <link name="onMassAction">ns = ${ $.ns }, index = listing_massaction:massaction</link>
            </imports>
        </settings>
    </insertListing>
```

> **And make sure your listing file follows like this : vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_address_listing.xml**

> **Also you can check the data source in vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/di.xml**

***If you get a reference for the Magento_Customer module then you achieved it. and also your all questions are solved there.***

Comment: Thanks for the referance